Screenshot of the Week #130
This contest is over.
Hello and welcome to the 130th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Joachim's screenshot from metro-exodus won with 19 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for (a little less than) a week, until December 9, 2024, then have a week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at December 16, 2024, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

No Theme
There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

I waited an extra day in the hope I would not have to congratulate myself, but meh..

That one was impossible to beat, honestly.

@pinckerman I don't know, it's not the most realistic screenshot I've ever seen but it does look great

Thanks, pinckerman! Yeah, @Clockwork, I do look forward to SotW #258-ish :)

@Dragonrage I think you forgot to change the image featured on the main site :)

@Joachim it's Aloy, I'm not going to complain

@Joachim thanks for the reminder. ill fix that

@pinckerman Really, you wouldn't rather look at pieces of rotting wood in murky water?

@Joachim I'd look at those water physics any day x)

It looks like the Force was with the Jedi today.

@Clockwork As it should be :)

Exploring unknown planet in star-wars-jedi-survivor


I see the light...

elden-ring


For a moment I almost hesitated to not add an alt text to the screenshot because I had no idea how to describe it succinctly (yeah, I have a philosophy to always add an alt text).

When you really needed a health pack. warhammer-40k-space-marine-2


Bruva, I am hit!
